# How can I parse out elements in a "< tag >"?

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing

I have a string:

```
string =  <RECALL>first_name</RECALL>, I'd like to send you something.  It'll help you learn more about both me and yourself.  What is your email?"
```

I want to pull out the value "first_name" of the tag `<RECALL>`.

I used `gem crack`, but it doesn't behave as I expected:

```
parsed = Crack::XML.parse(string) =>

{"RECALL"=>"first_name, I'd like to send you something.  It'll help you learn more about both me and yourself.  What is your email?"}
```

Maybe XML parsing isn't the right way.  What is the way so that I could get the following, desired behavior, instead?

```
{"RECALL"=>"first_name"}
```

Comment: You you have to use that gem? It seems easier to use nokogiri.

Comment: yeah....I was using it as a short-cut to read the tags :(

Comment: I didn't know how to use nokogiri, and crack seemed easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's two ways you could get the content of the tags:

```
string =  "<RECALL>first_name</RECALL>"

firstname = string[/<RECALL>([^<]+)</, 1]
firstname # => "first_name"
```

Parsing strings containing tags gets tricky. It's doable for simple content, but once tags are nested or additional `<` or `>` show up, it gets a lot harder.

You can use a trick using an XML parser:

```
require 'nokogiri'
string =  "foo <RECALL>first_name</RECALL> bar"

doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(string)
doc.at('RECALL').text # => "first_name"
```

Note that I'm using `Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse`. That tells Nokogiri to only expect a partial XML document and relaxes a lot of its normally strict XML rules. Then I can tell the parser to find the `<RECALL>` tag and grab its contained text.

---

> ...wondering if there's a way to extract it (I use Crack to extract it, but it only works if the `<tag>` is at the end of the string.

This pattern matches mid-string:

```
str =  "foo <RECALL>first_name</RECALL> bar"
str[%r!<RECALL>([^<]+)</RECALL>!, 1] # => "first_name"
```

This pattern fails if the tag is not at the end of the string:

```
str[%r!<RECALL>([^<]+)</RECALL>\z!, 1] # => nil
```

And succeeds if it is at the end of the string:

```
str =  "foo <RECALL>first_name</RECALL>"
str[%r!<RECALL>([^<]+)</RECALL>\z!, 1] # => "first_name"
```

This is one place where a regexp pattern makes it easier to do something than using a parser.

Using a parser:

```
require 'nokogiri'
```

Normally we don't care where a tag occurs in a DOM, but if it's important we can figure out where it is in relation to the other tags. It won't always be this straightforward though:

This returns `nil` if the tag isn't at the end of the string/DOM:

```
str =  "foo <RECALL>first_name</RECALL> bar"
doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(str)
recall_node = doc.at('RECALL')
recall_node == doc.children.last ? doc.at('RECALL').text : nil # => nil
```

This returns the text of the node because it is at the end of the DOM:

```
str =  "foo <RECALL>first_name</RECALL>"
doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(str)
recall_node = doc.at('RECALL')
recall_node == doc.children.last ? doc.at('RECALL').text : nil # => "first_name"
```

This works because every node in a document has an identifier and we can ask whether the node of interest matches the last node in the DOM:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse("<node>first_name</node> text")
# => #(DocumentFragment:0x3ffc89c3d3e8 {
#      name = "#document-fragment",
#      children = [
#        #(Element:0x3ffc89c3cf9c {
#          name = "node",
#          children = [ #(Text "first_name")]
#          }),
#        #(Text " text")]
#      })
doc.at('node').object_id.to_s(16) # => "3ffc89c3cf9c"
doc.children.last.object_id.to_s(16) # => "3ffc89c3cec0"

doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse("<node>first_name</node>")
# => #(DocumentFragment:0x3ffc89c345cc {
#      name = "#document-fragment",
#      children = [
#        #(Element:0x3ffc89c342c0 {
#          name = "node",
#          children = [ #(Text "first_name")]
#          })]
#      })
doc.at('node').object_id.to_s(16) # => "3ffc89c342c0"
doc.children.last.object_id.to_s(16) # => "3ffc89c342c0"
```

Comment: thanks --- both of those.....I would need to explicitly state <RECALL> --- which is what I do now, but wondering if there's a way to extract it (I use Crack to extract it, but it only works if the <tag> is at the end of the string....

Comment: Yes it's possible, but why wasn't that a requirement in the question?

Comment: I was originally trying to solve for the local case -- but realized that I had two instances of different tags that needed to be parsed where I was using Crack...which fails when there is something outside of the tags (as you noted, it's not real XML.  So as you noted, I would need to look at regex....so comparing options and seeing how I can constrain the input string....

Comment: thanks, btw, looks like this is the answer so awarding it for now -- but may have questions later.

Comment: Questions later will need to be asked as separate questions.

Answer (score 2):

Does not look like valid XML to me. I would just try to use an REGEXP here:

```
string = "<RECALL>first_name</RECALL>, I'd like to send you something..."

/<RECALL>(.*)<\/RECALL>/.match(string)[1]
#=> "first_name"
```

Comment: You are right, it is not valid XML....I was using the XML parser as a cheat, but wasn't sure how to ask the question beyond saying I want to parse at <tag>...the benefit with Crack was it will tell me the value of the nodes without me calling it out....not absolutely necessarily since it's probably 2-5 different tags in total.